# Setting .htaccess for Wordpress in a subdirectory with 'Post name' permalinks

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to set up a Wordpress installation, where Wordpress is in a subdirectory, but where the subdirectory is always rewritten out of the URL.

I've been trying to follow a whole bunch of other questions / posts about doing this, but no one else's solutions seem to work for me, and a lot of the time they just get the pages to load, without removing the subdirectory from the URL, which is crucial for me.

I'm also hoping for a solution that will work the same locally (`http://localhost/wordpress`) as it will on a live server (`http://example-site.com`). However, I'll explain the problem from a local point of view:

My root folder is structured like this:

```
.htaccess
wp /* contains all wordpress core files */
wp-content /* custom wp-content folder, which is set to be pointed at in my wp-config */
wp-config.php
```

So, if we ignore the .htaccess, the site would be accessed by going to `http://localhost/wordpress/wp`, and the goal is to access it by just going to `http://localhost/wordpress`.

This was achieved using this .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 302 /wp/$ /wordpress/$1

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wp/$1
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, at this point, my wordpress installation was set to use default permalinks, which create pages like `http://localhost/wordpress?p=12`. I need to set this to a different permalink type, which uses URL segments rather than query parameters, like `http://localhost/wordpress/hello-world`. Once that setting is changed, I can no longer access other pages with that .htaccess (the home page still works fine though)

I tried using this .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ -
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /wordpress/wp/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Which now causes the sub pages to load, though the home page no longer does, nor do some asset files, like `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css`

I can't seem to find a solution that makes everything work at the same time!

I'd also like to mention that I have a very small understanding of writing .htaccess files, so if anyone is going to answer this, please explain things like I am an idiot, as I may not understand you otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I am considering that you have redirected the domain to the relavant folder, or on shared hosting you have setup the domain to point to your subfolder. I am also considering that you are adding the htaccess to the root. Here is code from the official codex for your situation.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?YourDomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog [L]
```

Replace yourdomain.com and blog with website address and directory. Delete everything else from the file. Then goto **settings > permalink** and change the permalink to what ever you want.

Comment: I've tried this solution, but it does not hide the subdirectory folder from the URL, so it's not quite what I need.

Comment: Are you sure you have pointing your domain to /root/wordpress ? For instance if you are using godaddy and point the domain to its subfolder then you dont even need the htaccess.

Comment: Sorry, I missed this in your answer at first.. the domain isn't pointed at the subfolder, it needs to be pointed at the root folder for this setup.

Comment: do you have mod_rewrite installed and  enabled on your server? It might sound stupid, as you said it was working for the second case. Just double checking. And is it a multisite?

Comment: If you are migrating the site from your local to live, I prefer using duplicator plugin. It takes care of every thing while transferring. Install it in your localhost and then just run it to create an installation file. It will automatically take care of the htaccess problem. But i dont know how it will work in your case as your domain is not pointing to the subfolder itself. But it might be worth a try. Secondly when ever i try to have a development and live environment. I modify my hosts file to make my local sites look like http://example.dev . It also looks a lot neater.

Comment: I am attempting to build a development set up base to use for multiple projects, so for the project this is most immediately for, it is a multisite, and I do have a local virtual host set up to simulate subdomains for it. Other projects will be the opposite. Also, you're right, I do have mod rewrite installed for sure, since I can get it to work for certain situations, just not quite everything I need. Thanks for trying to help with this though!